# Product Design: Text Orientation and Quantity

Tags: text, interface-design, alignment, branding

I have a question about how the quantity and orientation of text can impact on the user experience. Have a look at the attached sketch. It's supposed to show the logo above, and company name and product design below.

[image]

There's only enough space to place text rotated by 90 degrees. I have a few questions surrounding this arrangement, from a graphic design perspective.

1. Is this a poor way to present your brand to your customers?
2. Would it be better to avoid using text in this instance and use the company logo alone?
3. Is there some wisdom as regards how much text is too much? And I suppose, how much is too little?

Comment: I'm not sure anything can be clearly decided upon unless one knows what the actual logo (or a relative facsimile) looks like. There's the full "[Johnson & Jonson](https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Johnson_and_Johnson_logo.png)" logo.. or the "[J&J](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1101560913885315074/9KHsZD7M_400x400.png)" logo -- A brand guide would have restrictions/guideline for which to use or which is acceptable and that would play a large part in placements and/or rotation. In broad, general terms, rotating a logo is bad form - unless the brand guide permits.

Comment: @scott Thanks Scott. The logo itself can be placed right way up. It's essentially round. So I suppose one way to look at it is: would J&J ever contemplate writing their full name on it's side?

Comment: Most brand guides I've seen strictly forbid rotating a logo which has a horizontal orientation.  While it's not *impossible* such a use case exists, it's really up to each brand. I don't think J&J ever rotates their full name logo. If what you describe is the case, I'd use the round logo with left justified text below it, both right side up. But.. that's merely my inclination without all the actual details.

Comment: Possibly related, see this question [How do you decide text direction when written in a vertical direction](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/143242/how-do-you-decide-the-text-direction-when-written-in-vertical-direction/143247#143247) This question is different in that it is mainly about direction of the text, but others answer with opinions that are related, such as when it is acceptable. It's generally quite unusual, and in most cases should be used only when really necessary. Can't you redesign it? If not, then just using the logo may be a solution.

Comment: Also note that product design is generally off topic here.  I know it's still graphic related, but in graphic design we generally don't have such restrictions or limitations. We can usually redesign if there is a problem. If you already have a product, then redesigning may not be an option. In such a case, vertical text may be the only practical option.

Comment: Yeah, we can't really help with anything more than what's been said without seeing the text/logo and product

Answer (score 0):

If space is limited like in this particular case, I would consider using an icon-only version of the logo at top left of the UI. Many brands will include the symbol as a stand-alone permitted usage for specific applications.

Rotating the naming part is very confusing in my opinion. Instead find an alternative way to show the complete logo, like, in the preload screen, or in the settings menu overlay (if you have that), etc.

Also I think since this is presumably an app you are designing, you should probably consider the vertical setup as well and find the best balance for multiple screen sizes and orientations.

[image]

[image]